# KeyBinding not working in JForm

Tags: java, swing, jframe, key-bindings

I have left and right buttons in my JForm UI and I'd like to bind the "A" and "D" to those buttons. I've been trying to follow other posts on here about this, but I still can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my code for the buttons:

```
private void clickRightActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    this.evt = evt;
    try {
        lastScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum, xls.getAbsolutePath());
        nextScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum + 1, xls.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println();
        scoreSet(xls, sheetNum, rowNum - 2, "n", lastScore);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReviewingWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    giveScore.setText("SCORE = " + nextScore);
}   

private void clickLeftActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    SetImageSize(rowNum, reviewImages, pic);
    try {
        if (rowNum < imageCount - 1) {
            lastScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum + 2, xls.getAbsolutePath());
            nextScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum + 1, xls.getAbsolutePath());
        scoreSet(xls, sheetNum, rowNum, "p", lastScore);
        } else {
            lastScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum, xls.getAbsolutePath());
            nextScore = cellData(sheetNum, 1, xls.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReviewingWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    giveScore.setText("SCORE = " + nextScore);
}
```

And here's my code for the keyBinding:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int keyPress = e.getKeyCode();
    switch(keyPress) { 
        case KeyEvent.VK_D:
            clickRightActionPerformed(evt);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:
            clickLeftActionPerformed(evt);
            break;
    }

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a [key binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it looks like a `KeyListener`, which explains your core issue. Also, `clickRightActionPerformed(evt)` can't possible compile, the formal parameters for the method require an instance of `ActionEvent`, but you're trying to pass a `KeyListener`

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of reading ahead of your, I recommend starting with:

- [How to use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)
- [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

The first thing you want to do is decouple the functionality.  This means that the "move left" and "move right" operations are independent of how they might be called, for me, this starts with a `interface`, which describes the basic contract been provided...

```
public interface MovementController {
    public void moveRight();
    public void moveLeft();
}
```

(and yes, if it was me, I'd have a left and right `interface`, but I'm trying to keep it simple ;))

Next, you want to design some `Action`s which can interact with this `interface`

```
public class RightAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Controller controller;

    public RightAction(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        // Button text
        putValue(NAME, "Right");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        controller.moveRight();
    }

}

public class LeftAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Controller controller;

    public LeftAction(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        // Button text
        putValue(NAME, "Left");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        controller.moveLeft();
    }

}
```

And finally, we need to plumb it altogether...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Test extends JPanel implements Controller {

    public Test() {
        LeftAction leftAction = new LeftAction(this);
        RightAction rightAction = new RightAction(this);

        JButton leftButton = new JButton(leftAction);
        JButton rightButton = new JButton(rightAction);

        // Add buttons to the UI...

        InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "left");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "right");

        am.put("left", leftAction);
        am.put("right", rightAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void moveRight() {
        try {
            lastScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum, xls.getAbsolutePath());
            nextScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum + 1, xls.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println();
            scoreSet(xls, sheetNum, rowNum - 2, "n", lastScore);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReviewingWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        giveScore.setText("SCORE = " + nextScore);
    }

    @Override
    public void moveLeft() {
        SetImageSize(rowNum, reviewImages, pic);
        try {
            if (rowNum < imageCount - 1) {
                lastScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum + 2, xls.getAbsolutePath());
                nextScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum + 1, xls.getAbsolutePath());
                scoreSet(xls, sheetNum, rowNum, "p", lastScore);
            } else {
                lastScore = cellData(sheetNum, rowNum, xls.getAbsolutePath());
                nextScore = cellData(sheetNum, 1, xls.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReviewingWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        giveScore.setText("SCORE = " + nextScore);
    }

}
```

As a common recommendation, it's best to base your UI on a `JPanel` rather then a `JFrame`, `JFrame` is a compound component, which just adds to complexity to it's over all management, starting with a `JPanel` as the base component allows you more freedom and allows you to add it to what ever container you want later